Angular Global CLI not updating
I am trying to update my global Angular CLI version but I can see the previous version always showing.
What I am doing for that:

Uninstall the global angular version (sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli)
NPM Cach clean (sudo npm cache clean --force)
NPM Cach verify (sudo npm cache verify --force)
Re-Install CLI globally (sudo npm install -g @angular/cli)

After that when I checked the global version, I saw it still showing the previous version.
Please see the attachment below:

